# Facebook API non-facebook Photo Tagging Intergration

Tags: javascript, facebook

Would it be possible to allow logged in facebook users to "tag" their friends or anyone really in a photo NOT hosted on facebook?

eg.. photos pulled from Google Picasa?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ha ha ha, should have Googled it properly first!

http://developers.face.com/ - Seems to do the trick! :D